Pre-Rendering: <head>, CSS gets rendered above the meta tags
"nuxt": "^3.9.1"
I currently have the problem that the Facebook URL Debugger cannot find the above tags. I read elsewhere that this may be because style information () in the head is above it.
The app retrieves the data via an API and generates the structure and pages from it. Then pages are pre-rendered.
I use useHead in the index.vue component:
useHead({
  title:
    page.value.name !== "Home" ? `${page.value.name} - ${appName}` : appName,
  meta: [
    { name: "description", content: page.value.metaDescription },
    { property: "og:description", content: page.value.metaDescription },
    {
      property: "og:title",
      content:
        page.value.name !== "Home"
          ? `${page.value.name} - ${appName}`
          : appName,
    },
    {
      property: "og:image",
      content: page.value.ogImage ? page.value.ogImage.url : "",
    },
    { property: "og:type", content: page.value.ogType },
  ],
  style: customCss,
});

After the pages have been generated and I examine the source code, I notice that all CSS was generated before the metadata:
<head>
[...]
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/entry.6m9pvrRw.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/FreedaMainFooter.UFGiSsJN.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/useGetPageUuid.B52ovy1O.css">
<link rel="preload" as="fetch" crossorigin="anonymous" href="/_payload.json?964e71c7-0f0c-40bc-b1ca-3ecca008762d">
<link rel="modulepreload" as="script" crossorigin href="/_nuxt/CrwkEhHD.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" as="script" crossorigin href="/_nuxt/B0k1ERQI.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" as="script" crossorigin href="/_nuxt/CnoOWoy4.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" as="script" crossorigin href="/_nuxt/Dw8oOQIz.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" as="script" crossorigin href="/_nuxt/CnOB2gJx.js">
<link rel="prefetch" as="script" crossorigin href="/_nuxt/DM6PhP7n.js">
<link rel="prefetch" as="script" crossorigin href="/_nuxt/CtUtV4mN.js">
<link rel="prefetch" as="script" crossorigin href="/_nuxt/DEqVE1xF.js">
<link rel="prefetch" as="script" crossorigin href="/_nuxt/NOIwMN2m.js">
<link rel="prefetch" as="script" crossorigin href="/_nuxt/CztP6LMI.js">
<link rel="prefetch" as="script" crossorigin href="/_nuxt/Bjt24Ym4.js">
<meta name="description" content="Yo!">
<meta property="og:description" content="Yo!">
<meta property="og:title" content="Business Pro">
<meta property="og:image" content>
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
[...]
</head>

As a result, the Facebook Share Debugger, for example, cannot even reach the meta tags.
How can I ensure that the meta data in the page source code is always rendered above the style information?
